# How to get notified using Broadcast Receiver in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I need to get notification about Bluetooth notification event so I planned to use the broadcast receiver. But I did not get any notification Please guide. Please help me what is the mistake I have done here?

```
   [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
   [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" })]
   public  class BroadcastMonitor : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {`
        // Do stuff here.

           String action = intent.Action;
           if (action.Equals(BluetoothAdapter.ActionConnectionStateChanged)) {
              int state = intent.GetIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.ExtraState,
                                                 BluetoothAdapter.Error);
              if (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected.Equals(action)) {
                 Console.WriteLine("on"); //not trigeered
              }

              if (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected.Equals(action)) {
                  Console.WriteLine("off"); //not trigeered
              }  
           }
        }
    }
```

//Main Activity code:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        RegisterReceiver(broadCastMonitor,new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"));
            base.OnResume();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(broadCastMonitor);
        base.OnPause();
    } 
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        broadCastMonitor=new BroadcastMonitor();
        IntentFilter filter = new 
             IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged);
    }
```

Comment: Did you acquire the `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` permission either via manifest or in runtime?

Comment: Already add in manifest.xml file :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the `IntentFilterAttribute` on your `BroadcastMonitor` class declaration. I am not sure if this creates a problem but I am sure you do not need that.

Comment: You are not registering the event (or calling you override method).   The Resume (RegisterReceiver)  and Pause (UnregisterReceiver) are changing the Event, but are you doing same when you start receiving?  Since there is a base class you have to make sure you  are calling OnReceive your code and not the base class code.

Answer (score 0):

```
       IntentFilter filter1;
    IntentFilter filter2;
    IntentFilter filter3;     
 protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {    
        filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected);
        filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested);
        filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected);

        LoadApplication(new App());

    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        this.RegisterReceiver(broadCastMonitor, filter1);
        this.RegisterReceiver(broadCastMonitor, filter2);
        this.RegisterReceiver(broadCastMonitor, filter3);
        base.OnResume();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        this.UnregisterReceiver(broadCastMonitor);
        base.OnPause();
    }  
       public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.Action;
        if (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected.Equals(action))
        {
            //Do something if connected
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Bluetooth Connected" + GlobalCache.ConnectedDeviceInfo.Name, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected.Equals(action))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Bluetooth disconnected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested.Equals(action))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Bluetooth disconnecting..", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```